# How to Move the Sidebar Down or Below Another Element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

On the homepage of my site, I want to push the sidebar down below another element (text and images) to the left on desktop. I have boxed the element I want to be full-width, and given it the CSS ID #latestbox, but it isn't obeying. I can't find anything relating to the sidebar in the style sheets or by right-click-inspect, so is it possible to just shove it down by ordering the latestbox element to override it?

Or are you pretty sure the sidebar ID is defaultsidebar, something like that, and can move it below the element somehow with that?

Comment: can you provide some code ?

Comment: Do you mean scrollbar?

Comment: try bootstrap affix.

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could work with? That will make it more likely you'll get a high quality answer to your question.